# mutate_geocode (ggmap) | Error "Results must be all atomic, or all data frame"

Tags: r, ggmap

## The issue

I am attempting to use `mutate_geocode` to geocode a set of 48K addresses. The actual geocode function seems to be working just fine, but once the geocoding finishes, I get an error stating:

> Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels"), .id, id_as_factor): Results must be all atomic, or all data frames

I am not sure why I'm running into this, as I've tried using the same code to geocode a smaller subset of the full 48K file and no errors were returned. Can anyone point me in the right direction in troubleshooting this? Below is the code I'm running, the relevant details of my R set-up.

## The Code Being Used

```
# load up the ggmap library
library(ggmap)
library(qdap)
library(plyr)
# get the input data
infile <- "DistinctAddressesAlleg_20170906_1"
data <- read.csv(paste0(infile, '.csv'))
data$address <- as.character(data$FullAddress)
register_google(key = "removed",
                account_type = "premium",
                day_limit = 150000)
data_geocoded <-
  data %>% mutate_geocode(address,
                          output = "more",
                          override_limit = TRUE,
                          key = key)
```

## R Set-up

- R v3.4.1
- RStudio v1.0.153
- ggmap v2.7

Comment: I should mention that some of the 48K addresses failed to geocode (either ZERO_RESULTS returned, or the ocassional 500 internal server error in response to a geocode request.

Comment: Is it a bad idea to expose what looks like a premium account API key in public?

Comment: Crap, I thought I took that out. Thanks for pointing that out. Removed it now.

Comment: History is visible, I've raised a flag for the moderators to hopefully delete it. You might want to revoke it and create a new API key!

Comment: Thanks spacedman, I am doing that now.

Comment: If I can provide any more detail to help troubleshoot, please let me know ☺️

Comment: Just wanted to check in and see if there is anything I should provide in my post to help get a response? If I am missing something, or not following posting best practices please let me know. I am new to posting on stackoverflow (though I've been using it as a reference for years).

Comment: Its hard for people to answer questions that might depend on your exact inputs, and also it seems you need a premium google key so that brings the field of possible answerers down. Have you tried *all* the 48k codes in small blocks? Is it a particular row that is causing the fail? The error happens at the end possibly because that's when mutate_geocode tries to assemble all the results and something isn't right, so you might have to debug this with R's debugging tools...

Comment: Seconding what Spacedman said... it's hard for others to troubleshoot when we can't reproduce the problem. I believe ggmap's `mutate_geocode()` is a wrapper around `geocode()` in the same package. Take a look at the code within & try running it line by line (there's only 3) to see which step is causing it to fail? If `geocode()` is working fine, maybe the problem lies with data frame creation in the final step.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, spacedman and Z.lin. I do think it's likely particular row or rows in the input file, but I don't know how to identify that row. Could you suggest what debugging tool could help me with this? I want to see what exactly is happening when the code fails, but I don't know how to do that. Sorry,.  Know that is a noob question. I have looked online at profiling and such but I'm a little lost.

Comment: You mentioned that the code worked on some subsets of the 48k. You can try the code on the first 24k. If it works try the second 24k, if it doesn't try on the first 12k, etc. In short do a binary search till you isolate some small subset of the data that always causes the error, & paste that subset here. (The daily request limit for free users is 2500, so make sure the subset is waaaaaaaaay smaller than that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to run into the same problem with the geocode function, and I solved the issue by coercing to dataframe:

```
data_geocoded <- as.data.frame(geocode(data$address,
                               output = "more"))
```